# magento 2.3.1 "Catalog Category Link" widget blank

Tags: category, catalog, widget, magento2.3.1, link

I am trying to use the following widget:

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Widget\Link" anchor_text="ewrrewq" title="rqewrqrq" template="category/widget/link/link_block.phtml" id_path="category/482" }}
```

but nothing is displayed. I did some diggings and I found out that

```
Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Widget\Link
```

is a virtualType declared in

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml.
```

What bothers me is that I cannot seem to debug it at all. Looks like that block is silently failing to initialize, do you have any tips on how do handle this ?

EDIT: it seems that many of the widgets are not working although they work on a clean installation using the default theme. It might be the installed theme, I will disable it and see check again

Comment: I've tested in a clean 2.3.1 installation with sample data and I can't replicate your issue.

Comment: please check `id_path`

Comment: thanks for testing, it might be some of my addons then.

Comment: Yes, tested on a clean installation myself and it seems that it works. I will update my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is a little embarrassing but it might help somebody.

At some moment I deleted the categories from `url_rewrites`, for some dumb reason. The widget was looking for some data inside that table and since it didn't find it, it returned blank.

Comment: Hi, it's showing blank on mine site, too. how do i check if its missing?

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? This doesn't help at all. I've been trying to find the solution here for a couple of days now. I'm sure it's something stupid I'm overlooking too.

Comment: I accepted it myself :).
In my case, like I said it didn't find the category in the url_rewrite table.

Comment: It's really as described. Thanks for the saved time!
After I added URL rewrite for categories in widget (link) - it became not empty.